# What are these blue flames, and is there any treasure involving them?

Tags: genshin-impact

[image]

Just southeast of Qingce village lies this ruin of a bunch of destroyed buildings -- there is also a Domain of Frost Blessing at the top of the village.    There are these blue flames everywhere -- so I've been wondering what's their purpose, and if anything, if they lead to any treasure of any sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blue flames are just aesthetic in this particular area. You can't do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

These blue flames do not have any mechanical function. They are just ambiance.

They are a reference to Japanese folklore. Legend says, that souls of deceased people sometimes appear at night in form of [Hitodama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitodama). Floating balls of fire in various unnatural colors.

Comment: This appear in not-China though, is there an equivalent Chinese reference?